# Jquery .Click applies to all sub divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="lowerLayer">
    <div id="positionLayer">
        <div id="imageLayer">
            <div id="imageHolder" style="background-image: url('/Images/Loading/ajax-loader.gif');">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#lowerLayer
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Green;
    cursor: help;
}
#positionLayer
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: Red;
}
#imageLayer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: Blue;
    background-image: url('../Images/Large-image-holder.png');
}
#imageHolder
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: Aqua;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lowerLayer").click(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
                $(this).hide(0);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Edit:

the problem im having us that the click event seems to be applied to all sub divs i just want it to apply to "#lowerLayer"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* this will solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lowerLayer").click(function(e) {

            // Return if it's a child that's clicked:
            if (e.target !== this) {return;}

            // Otherwise continue:
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
                $(this).hide(0);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 but I'm a little surprised jquery doesn't have a more *jquery* way of describing !bubble

Comment: Seems not too jQueryish, but e.target is the place to look when you want to distinguish between the element that originated the event (e.target) and the element that captures it due to bubble (this).

Answer (score 2):

Leaving event delegation and bubbling aside, since I don't think it is relevant to the actual problem here.

The jQuery `hide()` method applies `display: none` to the styles for an element. If an element is not displayed, then none of its descendants are either. Likewise, `fadeTo()` reduces the opacity, which also has an effect on the descendents of an element.

Comment: the problem im having us that the click event seems to be applied to all sub divs i just want it to apply to "#lowerLayer"

Comment: Petoj, it's not being applied to all "sub-divs" - when a click event occurs it will bubble up through the DOM triggering clicks on all ancestors (unless it's stopped)

Comment: events bubble up (from child to parent), they do not trickle down - I think you'll find the event does only fire once. Put an alert in to prove it to yourself.

Comment: The event only triggers once but i dont want it to trigger if i click a sub div only #lowerLayer